# How to create a tree from a given parent child list but child node can't be created before its parent node?

Tags: algorithm, tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

A list contain parent and child. Here root node's parent is -1.  I have to create a tree from here but any child node can't be created before it's parent.

Parent child list

```
3 7
3 6 
2 5
-1 1
2 4
1 2
1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Below algorithm will work:

1. Initialise a `Map` from `Integer` to `List/Array[Integer]`. Here, `key` represents `Parent` and `List/Array[Integer]` represents `Childrens`.
2. Iterate over `parent child list` mentioned in question. For every entry, populate `Map` created in Step 1.
   i.e. For the example mentioned in Question, `Map` will look something like below:

   `-1 -> [1]
   1  -> [2, 3]
   2  -> [4, 5]
   3  -> [6, 7]`
3. Once you have `Map` prepared, sort `Map` by keys.
4. For each `Key, Value` in `Map`, Create Node for Parent and then for it's child. Follow this for remaining `Key, Value` Pair.

This will ensure that `Parent` will always be prepared before `Child`.

Comment: @mos Did above answer helped you? Consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answer if it helped you.